# Как выделить активный пункт меню содержащий вложенные элементы?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, меню

Всем привет! Подскажите, как можно выделить активный пункт меню в моем случае?
проблема еще и в том, что здесь присутствует выпадающий список - нужно, чтобы при клике на одном из пунктов выделялся его содержащий. Как это можно реализовать?

```js
$('.nav.navbar-nav li a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('activenav');
```

```css
 .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0.8;
 }
 .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0;
   -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
   -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
   -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
   transition: all 800ms ease;
 }
 .dropdown-menu>li>a {
   padding: 8px 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
 .dropdown-menu>.last>a {
   border: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="../index.php">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>


        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

        <li class="last">
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно именно при клике? Тогда тут без JavaScript не обойтись.

Вообще уточни вопрос - не очень понятно, что нужно и как должно работать.

Comment: да при клике на выбранный пункт меню он подсвечивается активным. пойдет и джава

Comment: пробовал через скрипт - не выходит..
$('.nav.navbar-nav li a[href="'+window.location.pathname+'"]').parent().addClass('activenav');

Comment: window.location.pathname показывает ссылку вида index.php,а у меня все ссылки относительные вида ../index.php - может быть в этом проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пройтись вверх по дереву элементов с помощью методов [`.parent()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) и [`.prev()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8):

```js
$('.navbar-nav .dropdown>ul>li>a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().prev().addClass('activenav');
})
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.activenav {
  background: orange;
}

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
  transition: all 800ms ease;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown-menu>.last>a {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Содержит вложенные элементы</a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"></a></li>
      </ul><!-- end dropdown-menu -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```